# npm start refuses to work after adding React-Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, npm

Am facing a problem in `React js` ,when i installed bootstrap using npm , the project refused to run in the browser with `npm start` command.

I was following this React-Bootstrap link https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started.html

So below is the error am getting:

> sh: react-scripts: command not found npm ERR! file sh npm ERR! code
>   ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno ENOENT npm ERR! syscall spawn npm ERR!
>   food_app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start` npm ERR! spawn ENOENT npm
>   ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the food_app@0.1.0 start script. npm ERR!
>   This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional
>   logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /Users/haleem/.npm/_logs/2017-10-17T12_58_51_812Z-debug.log

Comment: try `npm cache clean` and install the dependency again.

Comment: Ok , is that  the command

Comment: I tried it but it gives me this `npm ERR! As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command with --force.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/haleem/.npm/_logs/2017-10-17T16_08_05_371Z-debug.log
Haleems-MBP:food_app haleem$`

Comment: You need to first run an `npm install` to install `react-scripts` from `create-react-app`. Have you done `npm install --save create-react-app`?

Comment: No i havent @ChaseDeAnda, i am trying out `npm cache verify`

Comment: You need to run those commands first. You're getting the errors because you haven't installed those packages locally.

Comment: Ok @ChaseDeAnda let me run it , is it `npm install` or `npm install --save create-react-app`?

Comment: Depends. Is it an existing project or new project. For new project do `npm install --save create-react-app` for existing project do `npm install`.

Comment: Ok it's existing let me try it out

Comment: THANKS @ChaseDeAnda it worked successfully , post the answer and i reward you a mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the packages before running it locally:

For new projects:

```
npm install --save create-react-app
```

For existing projects:

```
npm install
```

Comment: This is strange, i created a new react app, and ran it, server started well, and showed default app.js content on webpage. then i added bootstrap using `npm install bootstrap` after getting this installed, again did `npm start`, this time it started giving errors. Again had to do `npm install` to install needed dependencies. Not i am not understanding, were some (already installed) dependencies removed automatically when i installed bootstrap, or bootstap required some addition dependencies to be installed?

Answer (score 0):

Problem : downloaded react-bootstrap in React.js and begun having problems.
The project had 'npm start' command error, with another issue below.

'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

even 'npm cache clean' command failed, and 'npm install' also failed.

Solution : npm install -g npm@9.6.6